# Rails - Add HTML attribute without setting a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to create an image_tag and specify a data- attribute that does not have any value set to it.  I'm trying to add data-tooltip, for use with Foundation 5 tooltips.  It seems that if any value is actually set to this, Foundation uses the same tooltip text every time and ignores the title attribute of that element (so every tooltip will say whatever the first one you hovered on was... which seems buggy in and of itself on Foundation's part also)

This is what I need to generate:

```
<img src="[whatever]" title="My Tooltip" data-tooltip />
```

This will not work for me:

```
<img src="[whatever]" title="My Tooltip" data-tooltip="[insert anything here]" />
```

I have tried a number of different combinations, and read documentation, but it seems no matter what I put as the value, it ends up generating it like data-tooltip="null", or true, or false, or any string I pass.

```
image_tag(my_image, class: 'has-tip', title: "My Title Here", data: { tooltip: true })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to pass in empty string as follows:

```
image_tag(my_image, class: 'has-tip', title: "My Title Here", data: { tooltip: "" })
```

Comment: This actually does work with Foundation at least (I could have sworn I tried it previously), but it does still place data-tooltip="" in the tag.  Is there any way to remove the ="" part all together so that it is only data-tooltip without the =""?

Comment: @Ryan, unfortunately not.  Every attribute needs a value.  Even the boolean attributes such as `disabled` or `readonly` which don't need a value ultimately get a value.  Please refer to the source here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L64.  So the best thing for your case is probably a false value or empty string.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4.1.4 using above tip `:"data-tooltip" => ''` renders data-tooltip without value.

Comment: In rails 5 this does not do the job for 'required' attr. I still get required="required"

Answer (score 0):

For an attribute with no value like *multiple* `<input multiple type="file">`, you can override the attribute default name, by uppercasing and setting an empty string. For example `input_html: { Multiple: '' }` But this is a hack.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 5, I was trying to add `itemscope` attribute with no value in the following link tag scenario:

```
    <%= link_to example_path(@example) do %>
      <span>
        <%= @example.name %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
```

I needed the resulting html `a` tag to show the `itemscope` attribute without any value like so:

```
<a itemscope href="example/path">
    <span>
       some text
    </span>
</a>
```

Notice the `itemscope` has no `=""` or `itemscope="itemscope"`.

I tried solutions from SO and other places and the only thing that worked for me was adding the following to the `link_to` tag: `" itemscope" => ''`. Notice the space between the first double quote and the word `itemscope`.

This seems to generate the desired outcome and also validated as schema.org tag on google (that is what i used the tag for).