# Data attribute with no value in Rails link helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a Rails app with Foundation 4.3.2 which uses boolean data tags to target elements.

If I want to generate something like:

```
<a href="#" data-section-title>Section 2</a>
```

What does my Rails helper function look like?

```
<%= link_to "Section 2", "#", :"data-section-title" %>
```

...doesn't work, get a syntax error from Rails.

Comment: If you're using ERB, you need to put the link_to inside a `<%=`, e.g. `<%= link_to ... %>`.   The third argument to link_to needs to be a hash of options, so you need to say `:"data-section-title" => something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Section 2", "#", data: {section_title: true } %>
```

Will generate the following code:

```
<a href="#" data-section-title="true">Section 2</a>
```

That should work.

Comment: Is a string "true" going to be the same thing as the boolean?

Comment: Yes it will be, give it a try :)
There is no way with rails helper to produce the data without a value, but you will get the same result for what you are looking for.

Comment: You can, but it isn't well explained (or at least I don't find it in docs). You need to assign a blank string to the HTML attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to assign to the data-attribute a blank string, like

```
<%= link_to "Section 2", "#", data: {"section-title": "" } %>
```

Comment: It results in `data-section-title=""` (Rails 4.2)

Comment: @kolen It could be a feature added in Rails 4.3. You can test that, in newest Rails versions, assigning a blank string produces a non valued data attribute

Comment: BTW, attributes with empty string value and without value are [equivalent in html](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes) (not sure if completely equivalent in resulting DOM)

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to "Section 2", "#", :"data-section-title" => true
```

Comment: Hi Chris!  Your solution produces: `<a data-section-title="true" href="#">Section 2</a>`.   According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308537/rails-add-html-attribute-without-setting-a-value), there is no way to produce attributes without values using rails helpers.  Logan you can just code the HTML by hand if that's what you really want, else just use "" or true.